# Why My server application freeze after several clients connected?

Tags: indy, delphi-xe7

i am using `indy` `TidTcpserver` inside my server application its working good but some times after 10 clients connected my server application got a deadlock and stop from response here is my server execute and broadcast protocol codes

**Tcp server execute**

```
procedure TfMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
  Command: String;
  Params: array[1..10] of String;
  ParamsCount, P: Integer;
  PackedParams: TPackedParams;
  IdBytes: TIdBytes;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  ReceiveParams, ReceiveStream: Boolean;
  Size: Int64;
begin
  Connection := Pointer(AContext.Data);
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  ReceiveParams := False;
  ReceiveStream := False;
  Command := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn; //read command

  if Command[1] = '1'  then //command with params
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
    ReceiveParams := True;
  end
  else if Command[1] = '2' then //command + memorystream
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
    ReceiveStream := True;
    MS.Position := 0;
  end
  else if Command[1] = '3' then //command with params + memorystream
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
    ReceiveParams := True;
    ReceiveStream := True;
  end;

  if ReceiveParams then //params is incomming
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadBytes(IdBytes, SizeOf(PackedParams), False);
    BytesToRaw(IdBytes, PackedParams, SizeOf(PackedParams));
    ParamsCount := 0;
    repeat
      Inc(ParamsCount);
      p := Pos(Sep, String(PackedParams.Params));
      Params[ParamsCount] := Copy(String(PackedParams.Params), 1, P - 1);
      Delete(PackedParams.Params, 1, P + 4);
    until PackedParams.Params = '';
  end;
  if ReceiveStream then //stream is incomming
  begin
    Size := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadInt64;
    AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadStream(MS, Size, False);
    MS.Position := 0;
  end;

  if Command = 'LOGIN' then
  begin
    usrnm := Params[1];
    passwd := params[2];

    if not userexists(usrnm, passwd) then
      AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteLn('INVALIDPASSWORD')
    else
    begin
      userslq.Close;
      userslq.SQL.Clear;
      userslq.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = "'+ trim(usrnm) +'"  AND `password` = "' + trim(passwd) + '"');
      userslq.Open;
      if NOT userslq.IsEmpty then
      begin
        SendCommandWithParams(Connection, 'SENDYOURINFO', IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID) + Sep);
        userslq.Close;
      end;
      userslq.Close;
      userslq.SQL.Clear;
      userslq.SQL.Add('UPDATE `users` SET `lastlogin` = :Date, `timeslogin`=(`timeslogin`+1) WHERE `users`.`username` = :uname;');
      userslq.ParamByName('uname').AsString := trim(usrnm);
      userslq.ParamByName('Date').AsDate := Now;
      userslq.ExecSQL;
      userslq.Close;
    end;
  end;

  if Command = 'TAKEMYINFO' then //login ok, add to listview
  begin
    Connection.Name := Params[1];
    Connections.Add(Connection);
    AddConnectionToListView(Connection);
  end;
  if Command = 'TEXTMESSAGE' then
  begin
    BroadCastTextMessage(Params[1], Connection.UniqueID, Connection.Name, Connection.IP);
  end;

  if Command = 'DISCONNECTED' then
  begin
    DeleteConnectionFromList(Connection.UniqueID);
    DeleteConnectionFromListView(Connection.UniqueID);
  end;
  MS.Free;
end;
```

**broadcast Protocol and used procedures**

```
procedure TfMain.AddConnectionToListView(Connection: TConnection);
begin
  with lwConnections.Items.Add do
  begin
    Caption := Connection.Name;
    SubItems.Add(Connection.IP);
    SubItems.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', Connection.Connected));
    SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID));
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.DeleteConnectionFromListView(UniqueID: DWord);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to lwConnections.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if lwConnections.Items.Item[I].SubItems.Strings[2] = IntToStr(UniqueID) then
    begin
      lwConnections.Items.Delete(I);
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfMain.DeleteConnectionFromList(UniqueID: DWord);
var
  I, Pos: Integer;
begin
  Pos := -1;
  for I := 0 to Connections.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if TConnection(Connections.Items[I]).UniqueID = UniqueID then
    begin
      Pos := I;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if Pos <> -1 then
    Connections.Delete(Pos);
end;

procedure TfMain.BroadCastTextMessage(const TextMessage: String; const FromUniqueID: DWord;
  const FromName: string; const dip: string);
var
  I: Integer;
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  for I := 0 to Connections.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Connection := Connections.Items[I];
    if Connection.UniqueID <> FromUniqueID then
      SendCommandWithParams(Connection, 'TEXTMESSAGE', FromName + Sep + TextMessage + Sep + dip + Sep);
  end;
end; 

procedure TfMain.SendCommandWithParams(Connection: TConnection; Command, Params:String);
var
  PackedParams: TPackedParams;
begin
  if not TIdContext(Connection.Thread).Connection.Socket.Connected then
    Exit;
  TCPServer.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    PackedParams.Params := ShortString(Params);
    with TIdContext(Connection.Thread).Connection.Socket do
    begin
      WriteLn('1' + Command);
      Write(RawToBytes(PackedParams, SizeOf(PackedParams)));
    end;
  finally
    TCPServer.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

on connect server event

```
procedure Tfmain.TcpServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection : TConnection;
begin
  Connection := TConnection.Create;
  Connection.IP  := AContext.Connection.Socket.Binding.PeerIP;
  Connection.Connected := Now;
  Connection.UniqueID := GetTickCount;
  if Connection.UniqueID = LastUniqueID then
    Connection.UniqueID := GetTickCount + 1000;
  LastUniqueID := Connection.UniqueID;
  Connection.Thread := AContext;
  AContext.Data := Connection;
end;
```

**Updated**

by following remy answer and his great details i started to do synchronize but in remy answer i am confused about `TCriticalSection` also i will have to rewrite the client code to be able to do same as his code doing , so i had to go with thread synchronize first here is example of what i did by following remy code  i did some manage and removed database temporarily to avoid confusing here is the code of trying synchronization UI inside server execute

```
if Command = 'LOGIN' then
begin
  if Password <> Params[1] then
    AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteLn('INVALIDPASSWORD')
  else
    SendCommandWithParams(Connection, 'SENDYOURINFO', IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID) + Sep);
end;
if Command = 'TAKEMYINFO' then //login ok, add to listview
begin
  Connection.Name := Params[1];
  Connections.Add(Connection);
  AddConnectionToListView(Connection);// this is not safe i know and thats what makes me confused so in this procedure call i do same as remy doing 
end;
```

```
procedure TfMain.AddConnectionToListView(Connection: TConnection);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Item: TListItem;
    begin
      Item := lwConnections.Items.Add;
      try
        Item.Caption := Connection.Name;
        Item.SubItems.Add(Connection.IP);
        Item.SubItems.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', Connection.Connected));
        Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID));
      except
        Item.Delete;
        raise;
      end;
    end
  );
end;
```

is this correct to synchronize ? whats makes me confused is this thread synchronize by itself ? i mean there is no thread class to execute and synchronize is this correct way ?

**Updates about synchronize**

Remy answer helps me i thanks him too much , but iam trying to understand thus synchronize part i found some ways on google as example include 
`idsync` in my uses

and call it like this as example

```
uses 
idsync;
// and in server execute i call TiDNotify To synchronize what ever i want ?


    procedure TfMain.DeleteConnectionFromListView;
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
      for I := 0 to lwConnections.Items.Count - 1 do
      begin
        if lwConnections.Items.Item[I].SubItems.Strings[2] = IntToStr(linetToID) then
        begin
          DeleteConnectionFromList(linetToID);
          lwConnections.Items.Delete(I);
          Break;
        end;
      end;
    end;


        procedure TfMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
        var
          Connection: TConnection;
          Command: String;
          Params: array[1..10] of String;
          ParamsCount, P: Integer;
          PackedParams: TPackedParams;
          IdBytes: TIdBytes;
          MS: TMemoryStream;
          ReceiveParams, ReceiveStream: Boolean;
          Size: Int64;
        begin
          Connection := Pointer(AContext.Data);
          MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
          ReceiveParams := False;
          ReceiveStream := False;
          Command := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn; //read command

          if Command[1] = '1'  then //command with params
          begin
            Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
            ReceiveParams := True;
          end
          else if Command[1] = '2' then //command + memorystream
          begin
            Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
            ReceiveStream := True;
            MS.Position := 0;
          end
          else if Command[1] = '3' then //command with params + memorystream
          begin
            Command := Copy(Command, 2, Length(Command));
            ReceiveParams := True;
            ReceiveStream := True;
          end;

          if ReceiveParams then //params is incomming
          begin
            AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadBytes(IdBytes, SizeOf(PackedParams), False);
            BytesToRaw(IdBytes, PackedParams, SizeOf(PackedParams));
            ParamsCount := 0;
            repeat
              Inc(ParamsCount);
              p := Pos(Sep, String(PackedParams.Params));
              Params[ParamsCount] := Copy(String(PackedParams.Params), 1, P - 1);
              Delete(PackedParams.Params, 1, P + 4);
            until PackedParams.Params = '';
          end;
          if ReceiveStream then //stream is incomming
          begin
            Size := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadInt64;
            AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadStream(MS, Size, False);
            MS.Position := 0;
          end;

          if Command = 'LOGIN' then
          begin
            if Password <> Params[1] then
              AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteLn('INVALIDPASSWORD')
            else
              SendCommandWithParams(Connection, 'SENDYOURINFO', IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID) + Sep);
          end;
          if Command = 'TAKEMYINFO' then //login ok, add to listview
          begin
            Connection.Name := Params[1];
            Connections.Add(Connection);
             TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(Connection.AddToListView);
          end;
          if Command = 'TEXTMESSAGE' then
          begin
            BroadCastTextMessage(Params[1], Connection.UniqueID);
          end;
          if Command = 'GETLIST' then
          begin
            SendClientsListTo(Connection.UniqueID);
          end;
          if Command = 'DISCONNECTED' then
          begin
            linetToID :=  Connection.UniqueID;// fmain private string variable  
            TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(DeleteConnectionFromListView);
          end;
          MS.Free;
        end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Its `OnExecute` event is triggered in the context of a worker thread.  But your `TAKEMYINFO` and `DISCONNECTED` command handlers are *directly* accessing UI controls without synchronizing with the main UI thread.  That can easily cause deadlocks (amongst other problems, including crashes, killing the UI, etc). You MUST sync!

Also, is `userexists()` thread-safe?  Is `userslq`?  Your use of the `Connections` list is definitely *not* thread-safe.

Why is `SendCommandWithParams()` locking the server's `Contexts` list, especially when called by `OnExecute`? You don't need to do that.  You should be locking it in `BroadCastTextMessage()` instead.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TConnnection = class(TIdServerContext)
  private
    WriteLock: TCriticalSection;

  public
    Name: String;
    IP: String;
    Connected: TDateTime;
    UniqueID: Dword;

    constructor Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure AddToListView;
    procedure DeleteFromListView;
    procedure BroadcastTextMessage(const TextMessage: String);
    procedure SendCommandWithParams(const Command, Params: String);
    procedure SendLn(const S: String);
    function UserExists(const User, Passwd: string): Boolean;
    procedure UpdateLastLogin(const User: String);
  end;

constructor TConnection.Create(AConnection: TIdTCPConnection; AYarn: TIdYarn; AList: TIdContextThreadList = nil);
begin
  inherited;
  WriteLock := TCriticalSection.Create;
end;

destructor TConnection.Destroy;
begin
  WriteLock.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TConnection.AddToListView;
var
  LName: string;
  LIP: string;
  LConnected: TDateTime;
  LUniqueID: Dword;
begin
  // in case the client disconnects and destroys this object before 
  // TThread.Queue() can update the ListView, capture the values so
  // this object's fields are not accessed directly...
  //
  LName := Self.Name;
  LIP := Self.IP;
  LConnected := Self.Connected;
  LUniqueID := Self.UniqueID;

  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Item: TListItem;
    begin
      if (fMain = nil) or (fMai.lwConnections = nil) then Exit;
      Item := fMain.lwConnections.Items.Add;
      try
        Item.Data := Self;
        Item.Caption := LName;
        Item.SubItems.Add(LIP);
        Item.SubItems.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:mm:ss', LConnected));
        Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(LUniqueID));
      except
        Item.Delete;
        raise;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TConnection.DeleteFromListView;
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    var
      Item: TListItem;
    begin
      if (fMain = nil) or (fMai.lwConnections = nil) then Exit;
      Item := fMain.lwConnections.FindData(0, Self, True, False);
      if Item <> nil then Item.Delete;
    end
  );
end;

procedue TConnection.BroadCastTextMessage(const TextMessage: String);
var
  List: TList; // or TIdContextList if using a modern Indy version
  I: Integer;
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  List := Server.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Connection := TConnection(List.Items[I]);
      if Connection <> Self then
      begin
        try
          Connection.SendCommandWithParams('TEXTMESSAGE', FromName + Sep + TextMessage + Sep + dip + Sep);
        except
        end;
    end;
  finally
    Server.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end; 

procedure TConnection.SendCommandWithParams(const Command, Params: String);
var
  PackedParams: TPackedParams;
begin
  PackedParams.Params := ShortString(Params);
  WriteLock.Enter;
  try
    with Connection.Socket do
    begin
      WriteLn('1' + Command);
      Write(RawToBytes(PackedParams, SizeOf(PackedParams)));
    end;
  finally
    WriteLock.Leave;
  end;
end;

procedure TConnection.SendLn(const S: String);
begin
  WriteLock.Enter;
  try
    Connection.Socket.WriteLn(S);
  finally
    WriteLock.Leave;
  end;
end;

function TConnection.UserExists(const User, Passwd: string): Boolean;
var
  Exists: Boolean;
begin
  // if you give each client its own DB connection, or use
  // a thread-safe DB pool, you don't have to sync this ...
  // 
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure 
      if (fMain = nil) or (fMai.userslq = nil) then Exit;
      with fMain.userslq do
      begin
        Close;
        SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :uname AND `password` = :passwd;';
        ParamByName('uname').AsString := Trim(User);
        ParamByName('passwd').AsString := Trim(Passwd);
        Open;
        try
          Exists := not IsEmpty;
        finally
          Close;
        end;
      end;
    end
  );
  Result := Exists;
end;

procedure TConnection.UpdateLastLogin(const User: String);
begin
  // if you give each client its own DB connection, or use
  // a thread-safe DB pool, you don't have to sync this ...
  // 
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure 
      if (fMain = nil) or (fMai.userslq = nil) then Exit;
      with fMain.userslq do
      begin
        Close;
        SQL.Text := 'UPDATE `users` SET `lastlogin` = :Date, `timeslogin`=(`timeslogin`+1) WHERE `users`.`username` = :uname;';
        ParamByName('uname').AsString := Trim(User);
        ParamByName('Date').AsDate := Now;
        ExecSQL;
        Close;
      end;
    end
  );
end;

procedure TfMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // set this before activating the server
  TCPServer.ContextClass := TConnection;
end;

procedure TfMain.TCPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;
  Connection.Name := '';
  Connection.IP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  Connection.Connected := Now;
  Connection.UniqueID := ...;
end;

procedure TfMain.TCPServerDisconnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;
  Connection.DeleteFromListView;
end;

procedure TfMain.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Connection: TConnection;
  Command: String;
  Params: array[1..10] of String;
  ParamsCount, P: Integer;
  PackedParams: TPackedParams;
  IdBytes: TIdBytes;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  ReceiveParams, ReceiveStream: Boolean;
  S: String;
begin
  Connection := AContext as TConnection;

  Command := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn; //read command
  if Command = '' then Exit;

  ReceiveParams := False;
  ReceiveStream := False;

  if Command[1] = '1'  then //command with params
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, MaxInt);
    ReceiveParams := True;
  end
  else if Command[1] = '2' then //command + memorystream
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, MaxInt);
    ReceiveStream := True;
  end
  else if Command[1] = '3' then //command with params + memorystream
  begin
    Command := Copy(Command, 2, MaxInt);
    ReceiveParams := True;
    ReceiveStream := True;
  end;

  if ReceiveParams then //params is incomming
  begin
    AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadBytes(IdBytes, SizeOf(PackedParams), False);
    BytesToRaw(IdBytes, PackedParams, SizeOf(PackedParams));
    S := String(PackedParams.Params);
    ParamsCount := 0;
    while (S <> '') and (ParamsCount < 10) do
    begin
      Inc(ParamsCount);
      p := Pos(Sep, S);
      if p = 0 then
        Params[ParamsCount] := S
      else
      begin
        Params[ParamsCount] := Copy(S, 1, P - 1);
        Delete(S, 1, P + 4);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  MS := nil;
  try
    if ReceiveStream then //stream is incomming
    begin
      MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
      AContext.Connection.Socket.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadStream(MS, -1, False);
      MS.Position := 0;
    end;

    if Command = 'LOGIN' then
    begin
      if ParamsCount <> 2 then
      begin
        Connection.SendLn('INVALIDPARAMS');
        Exit;
      end;

      if not Connection.UserExists(Params[1], Params[2]) then
      begin
        Connection.SendLn('INVALIDPASSWORD');
        Exit;
      end;

      Connection.UpdateLastLogin(Params[1]);

      Connection.SendCommandWithParams('SENDYOURINFO', IntToStr(Connection.UniqueID) + Sep);
    end

    else if Command = 'TAKEMYINFO' then //login ok, add to listview
    begin
      if ParamsCount <> 1 then
      begin
        Connection.SendLn('INVALIDPARAMS');
        Exit;
      end;

      Connection.Name := Params[1];
      Connection.AddToListView;
    end

    else if Command = 'TEXTMESSAGE' then
    begin
      if ParamsCount <> 1 then
      begin
        Connection.SendLn('INVALIDPARAMS');
        Exit;
      end;

      Connection.BroadCastTextMessage(Params[1]);
    end

    else if Command = 'DISCONNECTED' then
    begin
      AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
      Exit;
    end;

  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: is it better if i use `TidNotify` ? or same as your code `TCriticalSection` is better  ?

Comment: `TIdNotify` is just a wrapper for `TThread.Queue()` in Delphi 8+.  You can use either one. But I would not suggest using `TIdNotify`/`TThread.Queue()` to serialize the socket writes. That would slow everything down. The `TCriticalSection` is to protect against multiple thread trying to write to the same socket at the same time. An alternative would be to give `TConnection` a thread-safe queue that you put outbound messages into, and then have `OnExecute` check that queue and send the messages. This way all reads and writes on a given socket stay within that socket's `OnExecute` event.

Comment: thank you very much , also i need to know something in `tlistitem`  you define a pointer of item data  `Item.Data := Self;` in my current server for define a pointer for each client connected i used  `Connection.Thread := AContext;`  `AContext.Data := Connection;` i updated on connect event in my question just i want know it will make any difference ?

Comment: I am setting `TListItem.Data` to point at the `TConnection` object. Makes the `RemoveFromListView` easier to implement (`FindData()`), and also allows you to more directly access a client when doing something with its associated `TListItem`. I merely changed the structure of `TConnection` itself to avoid having to use the `TIdContext.Data` property anymore.  It is better to manage 1 object per client that the server tracks for you, then trying to manage 2 separate objects that are linked together and being tracked manually.

Comment: i will have some difficulty to combine this method with my client and server is there other way that i can synchronize server execute by using TThread in commands as example `if command := 'something' then TThread.Synchronize(nil, callUIprocedure);`

Comment: I already showed you how to do that. What is the actual problem you are having with integrating this into your code?

Comment: i have to rewrite my client to be combined with the server when i use your code my client does not connect to server if there is a sample on synchronize multi commands inside the server execute will be more helpful iam scared to use Tidnotify it will not help me its only synchronize a one procedure

Comment: There are a bazillion examples floating around of how to use `TThread.Synchronize()` and `TThread.Queue()`, with class methods or anonymous procedures.  Please do some research. If you are having problems, you need to provide specific details. Just saying "it doesn't work" is useless. Please update your question to show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: i have to take some time to do some research , Thank you remy i will update with details after research

Comment: i updated the question with part that iam confused in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89984/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-martinloanel).

Comment: i just added update to my question to understand more about synchronize inside server execute is this right method ?

Comment: `TIdNotify` is deprecated (but not marked as `deprecated` yet) in favor of `TThread.Queue()`, though you can still use `TIdNotify` if you want (for now). However, you are still not passing data around in a thread-safe manner. For instance, to call `DeleteConnectionFromListView()` *safely*, derive a new class from `TIdNotify` and override its virtual `DoNotify()` method to call `DeleteConnectionFromListView()`. Store the desired ID value as a data member of the class and have `DoNotify()` pass it to `DeleteConnectionFromListView()` as an input parameter.

Comment: `TIdNotify.NotifyMethod()` is not adequate enough in this case, because another client thread could modify `linetToID` before a previous notify has been processed to use it. So each notify needs to carry its own `linetToID` value.

Comment: And we are dragging on this commenting too long.  If you have any further questions, please post new questions about them.